warning (readjpg): Exif resolution ...dpi x ...dpi differs from the input resol ution 72dpi x 72dpi
In a long document with many images (of which I am neither the author nor the supplier), I get several warnings of the form during the (lualatex) compilation:

warning (readjpg): Exif resolution ...dpi x ...dpi differs from input resolution 72dpi x 72dpi

As long as the images are of a reasonable size for the reader, can these warnings be ignored?
